# Triggering macro expansion in build.rs

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I want to create a macro using the crate [cpp](https://crates.io/crates/cpp), however this crate has issues with macro expansion.

#### Context

The crate works by taking `cpp!{ ... }` macros of inline C code, compiling their contents as functions, and replacing the macro call with the resulting function. This is triggered by calling `cpp_build::build("src/lib.rs")` in the `build.rs`.

#### Issue

As stated by the crate's authors, the `cpp!` macro is compiled before macro expansion can occur. This means it will attempt to interpret the arguments of the macro as-is and expand inside of the macro declaration.

Is there a way I can trigger the expansion of specific macros or files inside of the `build.rs` before I call the `cpp_build` function?

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is by not using macros (technically). `syn` crate has a `parse_file` function which you can call from the build script. Then you'd have to traverse the syntax tree and find actual macro invocations. `syn` has a `visit` feature (see module documentation), which will help you in doing so. When you locate macro invocations with `syn`, you can run the macros directly.

You'll then need to vendor your own versions of the macros (if they're not yours) which expose internals to the build script by removing `proc_macro` attribute from `Cargo.toml` and adding those versions to `dev-dependencies`.

Note that this will only work IFF you're not asking about macros nested within the `cpp!{}` macro - if you are, the internals of a macro can only ever be considered as a token stream semantically (even if it's plain Rust code) and syn will give you just that. You'll need to re-process the internal code manually with `syn::parse` if it's valid Rust. If it's C/C++ you'll have to vendor and extend a C/C++ parser with Rust macro support - but there's probably a better/simpler approach you could take.